# Additional checkboxes/radiobutton required for treeview

Tags: asp.net

I understand that treeview in asp.net comes with checkboxes option for usage. However, in my application, I will require 2 additional checkboxes or radiobutton on the righthand side of each leaf node of my treeview.

However, I seem to be unable to find a solution to this requirement, and i think treeview structure does not support this feature.

I'm new to asp and I'm not sure if there is any other class which i can use upon to implement this feature.

Hope I can have some ideas from you guys to implement this

All help is appreciated

Thanks!

Regards
bernerd

Answer (score 0):

The tree view control is quite limited however I've found this project http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43057/ASTreeView-Free-ASP-NET-TreeView-Control which has extended its functionality - check out the reference and see if it provides what you need OR use it as a base to extend it as your scope requires!